# expected pay off of an American option

Tags: asset-pricing

I find it hard to get an intuitive understanding of the expected pay off of an American option.

I read in this thread [expected payoff of an American put option](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/16618/expected-payoff-of-an-american-put-option)
but what I don't understand is why do we have $$e^{-r(\tau-t)}$$ in the expected pay off? (where $r$: risk-free interest rate, 
$\tau$: time to expiry
$t$: time
)

Am I right that this means that there is discounting? Why?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Economics.SE! You should look up "continuous compounding.